# Can one OnGestureListener object deal with two GestureDetector objects?

Tags: android, listener, gesturedetector

I am creating a View that needs to consume pretty much any gesture going.  To do this I created a ScaleGestureDetector and a GestureDetector.  I also created one listener class and realized I could have it implement every interface I needed; so I did.  This makes total sense for OnGestureListener and OnDoubleTapListener because they come from the same class, but:

- Will the ScaleGestureDetector expect its own listener class?
- If it's happy with the same class, will it expect its own object?
- Conversely, do I NEED to use the same listener with both detectors?

Experiment has confirmed the following:

- You can indeed use one listener class, but
- ScaleGestureDetector and GestureDetector can annoy each other if they consume the same event.  However
- It seems you can prevent this mutual irking by always calling the scale detector FIRST and then checking its isInProgress() method before running the regular detector:

  ```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  //let the ScaleGestureDetector try first
      mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  //if isInProgress() returns true then it's consuming the event
      if(mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) return true;
  //if isInProgress() returns false it isn't consuming the event
  //it's therefore safe to pass it to the regular detector
      mPrimaryDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      return true;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ScaleGestureDetector and GestureDetector can annoy each other if they
>   consume the same event. However It seems you can prevent this mutual
>   irking by always calling the scale detector FIRST and then checking
>   its isInProgress() method before running the regular detector

Personally, I have not found any issues by letting them both handle the same touch event.

The android `GestureDetector` has a [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#GestureDetector%28android.content.Context,%20android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,%20android.os.Handler,%20boolean%29) which takes a boolean `ignoreMultiTouch`. Setting `ignoreMultiTouch` to `true` will ensure that the `GestureDetector` touch event processing ignores any mutitouch events. (Android actually sets `ignoreMultiTouch` to `true` if the target API level is >= Froyo, so you probably won't need to explicitly set it.)

If you only call `mPrimaryDetector.onTouchEvent(event)`, when `mScaleDetector.isInProgress()` returns false, you will incorrectly get a long press event. The reason is the `GestureDetector` has the following code in its `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` to ensure it does not conflict with multitouch gestures:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
  if (mIgnoreMultitouch) {
    // Multitouch event - abort.
    cancel();
  }
  break;
```

`cancel()` will do what it says and cancel any single touch gestures. (If you're really curious you can look at that [GestureDetector code](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/view/GestureDetector.java&l=589) yourself; it actually uses a handler to send/remove messages).

Hope this helps anyone who was having the same issues I was.

Comment: That is fantastically useful, thank you!  I didn't know about `ignoreMultiTouch` at all.

Comment: By the way, the form the "annoyance" took was it seemed the `MotionEvent` was being altered by one listener class in a way that caused the other to crash.

Comment: @Noel looks like the ignoreMultiTouch parameter has been renamed to unused, and like it is named no longer used.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

To determine whether the MotionEvent is a multitouch event, simply use the `MotionEvent.getPointerCount() > 1`. So I think the following code will work well:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    } else {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't cover what happens if the pointer count changes: you'd have to filter somewhat by action, at the very least, and a multitouch gesture will often have pointers go down at slightly different times.

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    m_sGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    m_GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I assume `m_sGestureDetector` is the `ScaleGestureDetector`?  Anyway, this is like the code snippet I included at the end of my question except I also have `if(mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) return true;` between the detectors in case the scale detector is consuming the event.